# Title text not showing when creating UIButton

Tags: c#, ios, uibutton

I have a list full of strings and I'm trying to create a button foreach string in my list. All the buttons show up but the text does not. Here is my code.

```
private void ListStubs()
    {
        foreach (string stub in MyList)
        {
            UIButton button = new UIButton();

            button.Frame = new CGRect(27f, i, 290f, 35f); 
            button.SetTitle(stub, UIControlState.Normal);
            button.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(255, 255, 255);
            button.SetTitleColor(UIColor.LightTextColor, UIControlState.Normal);
            button.Alpha = 1;
            button.Layer.CornerRadius = 8;

            scrollView.AddSubview(button);

            sub += 58;

            scrollView.ContentSize = new CGSize(0, sub);

            i += 58;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Just figured it out, it was a problem with my string :S

Answer (score 1):

you need to set `button.Text` as well.

```
button.Text=stub;
```